# JUnit create dao fake object JAVA

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to test a class which is using dao. In my test class I have mocked the DAO and inject the mock into an instance of the class that I test. I am trying to make a fake object of the DAO class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private UserManagerDao umDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserManager um = new UserManager();

    @Before
    public void initializeMockito() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testGetUserId() {       

    }
```

This here are the methods from UserManager.class and Dao class

**userManager.class**

```
public long getUserId(String email) throws Exception {
    String[] partsOfMail = email.split("@");        
    return umDao.getUserId(partsOfMail[0], partsOfMail[1]);
}
```

**Dao class**

```
public long getUserId(String userName, String domain) throws Exception {
    String sql = msa.getMessage("sql.select.user_id");
    Object[] params = new Object[] { userName, domain };

    List<Long> result = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql, params, Long.class);

    if (result.size() > 0) {
        return result.get(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Is there unexpected behaviour, an exception etc...?

Comment: @Jonathan I do not know how to make a fake object of dao class.

Comment: That's fine, but it's not clear from your question what the problem is. It may help to add extra details. For example, if `umDao` is `null` or if it's not actually a mock object etc... It will help people answer your question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See comments:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private UserManagerDao umDao; // a mock object should present here 

    /* @InjectMocks should be able to create an instance 
       with mocks injected for you - you don't need to create it 
       yourself */
    @InjectMocks
    private UserManager um; // = new UserManager(); 

    /* Not required as you're using the MockitoJUnitRunner
       @Before
       public void initializeMockito() {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       } */

    // Add test annotation (assuming JUnit4 as you're not extending TestCase)
    @Test 
    public void testGetUserId() {   
        // Both these fields should not be null
        Assert.assertNotNull(umDao);
        Assert.assertNotNull(um);
    }
```

For more information take a look at [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) and [`InjectMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) documentation.

Mockito's documentation, which included many examples, can be found [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Comment: Now the test works. Thank you. Will you show me how to make a fake object of dao to test getUserId method please ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html), it's documentation 'by example' on how to use Mockito features.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? If you are asking how to mock some method in the DAO, this is a simple example.

```
@Test
public void testGetUserId() {       
    when(umDao.getUserId(<PARS>)).thenReturn(1L);
    assertThat(um.getUserId(<PAR>)).isEqualTo(1L);
}
```